# In Pydev setting a breakpoint, but breakpoint not hit on callbacks only

Tags: python

Ok, I am new to python and my code calls some library (which is  wrapping some C++ code) and I pass it a callback function on my side (as library needs to). The strange thing is that if I insert a breakpoint in my other part of the code, it will hit and deugger stops in eclipse but none of my breakpoints in the callback hit. The callback is sure called but the breakpoint is somehow ignored by PyDev. What I am doing wrong? The callback is obviously coming on a different thread. I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing `pdb` and just manually setting breakpoints in the code with `pdb.set_trace()`. This won't work in all multi-threaded cases, but I find that it works in many of them and is a big improvement over the native Eclipse/PyDev debugger.

Comment: Is PyDev or possibly Python known to have problems in debugging multi-threaded code?

Comment: PyDev is known for this. It doesn't handle any distributed debugging well. There are other editors than can do it better (e.g. Wing IDE or Komodo). This was actually the issue that finally pushed me over the edge to commit to Emacs for everything. I'm glad I did, now I rely more on the better command line tools for debugging and less on the editor, and while I am certainly no debugger expert, I feel it has helped me learn more about what's really going on.